# My application stops working when I enter a specific activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm trying to make an android app. When I choose an item from a list you go to another activity, but when I press the item I get this error(below) and the application dies. I can't figure it out, It worked a few hours ago, I just changed some margins on the textboxes in the .xml for the activity that start when I click the list item.

```
11-25 21:06:21.427: D/dalvikvm(725): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 3% free 6779K/6919K, paused 45ms, total 65ms
11-25 21:06:21.427: I/dalvikvm-heap(725): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 11715856-byte allocation
11-25 21:06:21.547: D/dalvikvm(725): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 603K, 11% free 6175K/6919K, paused 114ms, total 119ms
11-25 21:06:21.547: E/dalvikvm-heap(725): Out of memory on a 11715856-byte allocation.
11-25 21:06:21.547: I/dalvikvm(725): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
11-25 21:06:21.547: I/dalvikvm(725):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a14568 self=0x2a00b9e0
11-25 21:06:21.547: I/dalvikvm(725):   | sysTid=725 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073870640
11-25 21:06:21.557: I/dalvikvm(725):   | schedstat=( 1339266348 1125088991 664 ) utm=96 stm=37 core=0
11-25 21:06:21.557: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3336)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:427)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
11-25 21:06:21.566: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
11-25 21:06:21.576: I/dalvikvm(725):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-25 21:06:21.576: I/dalvikvm(725):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at com.example.lapp.legi.onCreate(legi.java:19)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-25 21:06:21.587: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 21:06:21.596: I/dalvikvm(725):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 21:06:21.616: I/dalvikvm(725):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-25 21:06:21.616: I/dalvikvm(725):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-25 21:06:21.616: I/dalvikvm(725):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 21:06:21.626: D/skia(725): --- decoder->decode returned false
11-25 21:06:21.626: D/AndroidRuntime(725): Shutting down VM
11-25 21:06:21.626: W/dalvikvm(725): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lapp/com.example.lapp.legi}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at com.example.lapp.legi.onCreate(legi.java:19)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  ... 11 more
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  ... 23 more
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3336)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:427)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
11-25 21:06:21.686: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  ... 26 more
11-25 21:06:24.386: E/Trace(742): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-25 21:06:24.746: D/libEGL(742): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
11-25 21:06:24.826: D/(742): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a0db078, tid 742
11-25 21:06:25.101: D/libEGL(742): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
11-25 21:06:25.116: D/libEGL(742): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
11-25 21:06:25.895: W/EGL_emulation(742): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-25 21:06:26.436: D/OpenGLRenderer(742): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZdXhwtyL

Comment: The image you are loading is too big and you are running out of memory...

Comment: hmm.. I havn't changed the pic, the same pic worked before, weird.

Comment: Sam is right.  Just because it ran last time doesn't mean it will next time.  To illustrate, answer this question. "How much memory is available to my application when it starts and will that memory be constant as it runs"?  Search here for lots of threads about reducing memory usage with bitmaps.

Comment: Yep, works now! I'm very confused because it worked with the same pictures before...
@Simon : well, it makes sense now when you put it like that.
Thx!

Comment: I found this in a TextView in your XML: `android:text="@string/0"` How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Like it says in the stack trace, it's an out of memory error. Because of the bitmap, which you are declaring in the XML element which starts at line 2.

Comment: Close, but not quite. The View that holds the Bitmap begins on the 2, the bitmap is loaded on line 5.

Comment: Well, then probably the XML element where the bitmap is used starts at line 2 (which makes sense, line 1 is usually document declaration). Edited the post.

Comment: The image can be used as background.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the link to the XML in the comment! Now I understand why you understand the problem so well ;)